# Spring with JPA: Queue concurrent access to JPA entity from different requests

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, concurrency, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Web Application with concurrent access to a certain resource. This resource holds a list of a certain numer of objects which might be fetched by a request. If the list is empty, no SomeClass Object should be returned any more

The resource looks like this:

```
public class Resource {

    private List<SomeClass> someList;

    public List<SomeClass> fetch() {
        List<SomeClass> fetched = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
        int max = someList.size();          
        if(max<=0) {
            return fetched;
        }

        int added = 0;
        while(added<max) {
            int randomIndex = Math.random(max-1);
            SomeClass someClass = someList.get(randomIndex);
            if(!fetched.contains(someClass)) {
                fetched.add(someClass);
                ++added;
            }
        }
        someList.remove(fetched);

        return fetched;
    }

}
```

This resource is loaded in the service layer, then accessed and saved back to the database:

```
@Service    
public class ResourceService {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceRepository repo;

    public List<SomeClass> fetch(long id) {
        Resource resource = repo.findOne(id);
        List<SomeClass> fetched = resource.fetch();
        repo.save(resource);
        return fetched;
    }

}
```

I tried to use @Transactional on the ResourceService#fetch method to avoid the problem that two concurrent requests might fetch a SomeClass object from the list although the list was already emptied by the first request but I'm not sure if this is the right approach... Do I have to use @Synchronized on the Resource#fetch method or introduce an explicit Lock in the service layer?

I need to make sure that only one request is accessing the Resource (fetching a list of SomeClass objects) without throwing an exception. Instead, subsequent requests should be queued and try to access the resource after the current request has finished fetching the list of SomeClass objects.

Comment: I think simply syncronizing with the Java `synchronize` will help, as by default all Spring beans are singleton (there is a single instance of your beanin JVM).

Comment: And do I stil need the @Transactional on the ResourceService#fetch mehotd? What if two requests load the resource from the DB, the first one fetches its list and then the second tries to fetch its list, although the resource has not been updated in the database yet, so both requests work with the same object!?

Comment: Sorry, I did not read carefully your question: Is a `Resource` a JPA entity ? In this case you could use [optimistic locking](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking#Optimistic_Locking). Do I understand correctly that the clients of your `ResourceService` == browsers?

Comment: Yes, Resource is a JPA entity.. The problem is, I cant use optimistic locking as this would throw an exception as far as I know, but I need the clients to be queued for accessing the resource, so the second requests accesses the Resource after the first has finished.. And yes, the clients of my resourceservice might be a browser app, or some native android app. I don't think this really matters..

Comment: What should happen when a browser requests a Resource and never updates it, i.e never release the lock?

Comment: As loading, fetching and saving the entity happens in the service fetch method, I dont see why this should ever happen.. Would a ReentrantLock with fair=true in the service method be a solution?

Comment: I am not sure you understand, that HTTP communication is asynchronous. This means the browser makes a request and then can wait indefinitely long. The typical Java synchronization mechanisms won't help you as you expect..

Comment: Dont know what you want to say, sorry.. Seems to me that http://stackoverflow.com/a/10514632 is about the same problem, so I will go with the ReentrantLock.. Thanks

Comment: If you found an answer, could you delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution was to introduce a [Blocking Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) in the @Service and add all incoming requests to it. A seperate thread is then [taking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) an element from the queue as soon as one was added and processing it.

I think this is the cleanest solution, as adding an [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) would block the request processing.

Comment: Do you have more information about how do you do that, any link? or github project with any example?